# Java 8: Comparator returns stream of Object instead of specific type

Tags: sorting, collections, java-8, java-stream

my question is about the new java 8 collection streaming possibilities. I do have a sorted map with Date objects as keys. Now I have written the method below, which has to find the previous key in the keyset of a given Date. So iterating over the keyset in reverse order it would be the first date which is prior to the given search date. Here is my implementation:

```
private Date getPreviousKey(Date searchKey, Map<Date, SchluesselSum> timesAndSums) {
return timesAndSums.keySet().stream()
    .sorted(Comparator.<Date>reverseOrder())
    .filter(date -> date.before(searchKey))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(null);
}
```

Now the problem is, that the call to .sorted(Comparator.reverserOrder()) returns a stream of java.lang.Object instead of Date and my compiler can't find .isLessOrEqual(...) in the .filter(...) call in the class Object.

How can I tell the .sorted method, or to be more precisely, the Comparator to return Date instead of Object?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? It compiles fine with javac for me ( you can even omit the explicit type parameter).

Comment: I am using Intellij IDEA 14.1 with Java 1.8.0_45

Comment: Weird.. I'm also using IntelliJ (which uses javac behind the scenes) and I don't have this problem. The problem is not with this piece of code definitely.

Comment: Compiles fine in Eclipse as well (even without explicit type parameter).

Comment: OK, thats weird. I used my own Date class implementation. Not working for this one but you guys are right. Its working fine for java.util.Date

Comment: Well, in first place don't extend a class called `Date` with `java.util.Date` to avoid naming confusions. Also you might consider using the new Java Time API.

Comment: My Date class is not just called Date. I just took java.util.Date so everyone can understand my problem without deeper knowledge of my own Date implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seemed to be due to your custom Date class.

Note however that if your map also happens to be a NavigableMap (all SortedMaps in the JDK are navigable), you can call [`NavigableMap#lowerKey`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NavigableMap.html#lowerKey-K-):

```
private Date getPreviousKey(Date searchKey, NavigableMap<Date, SchluesselSum> timesAndSums) {
  return timesAndSums.lowerKey(searchKey);
}
```

This will be more efficient (in terms of lines of code, readability and performance) than your current approach.

Comment: You, sir, saved my day! Thank you very much. You are right, it is MUCH more readable.

Comment: …and if the map isn’t sorted before the operation, a simple linear search using `.filter(date -> date.before(searchKey)).max(naturalOrder())` will be more efficient than using `sorted`. Utilizing a presorted order might look clever at the first glance, but it ignores that the sorting itself has costs *at least* as high as the linear search. Either the map is already sorted, then `lowerKey` is the way to go, or a linear search is unavoidable. Explicit sorting is only useful if you intend to keep the sorted data for more than one operation.